# Is a function return value possible as an array key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I made a lazy utility function that I wanted to pass as my arrays key but I was getting syntax errors, is it possible to pass a function inside the array as it's key?

```
function encloseAttrSelector(attr, value)
{
    return '[' + attr + '="' + value + '"]';
}
```

..

example (typically more than one pair):

```
var data = { encloseAttrSelector('name', 'username'):  row.first().text() };
```

Comment: No, you have to do it 2 steps, `var data = {}; data[encloseAttrSelector('name', 'username')] = row.first().text();` At least in current browsers that do not support the newest features.

Comment: Computed object property names is something that will be supported in the not so distant future by most browsers. Right now you'll have to do it in two lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In <strike>ES6</strike> ES2015 (the newest official standard for the language) yes, but in most real-life contexts no. You can however do this:

```
var data = {};
data[encloseAttrSelector('name', 'username')] = row.first().text();
```

The new ES2015 syntax is:

```
var data = { [encloseAttrSelector('name', 'username')] : row.first().text() };
```

That is, square brackets around what would normally be just the property name in an object initializer expression. Inside the square brackets can be any expression.

Answer (score 2):

For more than one pair, please do this:

```
var data = {};
data[encloseAttrSelector('name', 'username')] = row.first().text();
```

Comment: I'm unclear why you say that `return {attr:value}` would work for a single pair. Your second one works, but the first one won't (in ES5)

Comment: @somethinghere Removed that bit. Thanks!